# Definite integral involving powers and trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Is it possible to evaluate the following integral?

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
{m \over m + x^{ak}\left[\,x^{2} + d^{2} + 2dx\cos\left(t\right)\,\right]^{-a/2}}
\,{\rm d}t
$$

I am not able to find any related formula, while I think ${\tt Mathematica}$ only solves it for specific a values.

Note that this integral follows from the expected value of 
${m \over m + x^{ak}\left[x^{2} + d^{2} + 2dx\cos\left(t\right)\right]^{-a/2}}$
over the uniform circular angle $t$ in $\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$ with
PDF ${\rm f}\left(t\right)={1 \over 2\pi}$.

Perhaps there is an indirect way to get this integral as well. Best regards.

Comment: It would be surprising to me that you find a general formula for this class of integrals. If I am wrong making this statement, please let me know.